# POSIX thread scheduling policies

Tags: posix

what is the difference between `PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED` and `PTHREAD_EXPLICIT SCHED`? By default which `sched` will be there and how to set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it took `PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED`

The difference is in the name itself: `INHERIT` is inherited from parent, explicit is declared explicitly

Comment: @Gughan Remember to accept (click on the "V" and make it green) if the answer is, for your, the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By Default is PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED, not PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED.

```
/* Scheduler inheritance.  */
enum
{
  PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED,
#define PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED   PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED
  PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED
#define PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED  PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED
};
```

[You can check it here](http://h30266.www3.hpe.com/odl/vax/opsys/vmsos73/vmsos73/6493/6101pro_015.html)