# default scheduled policy: omitting use of pthread_attr_setschedpolicy

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads

What will happen if I donot set the scheduling policy attribute of the thread attributes object with pthread_attr_setschedpolicy? What if I directly go ahead and create and cancel the thread from main loop?
In what case does a system needs pthread_attr_setschedpolicy to be set before any thread creation from the application? What if I leave the scheduler policy unset in case where the system requires the application to set that?

Comment: I guess the value will have a default value (I assume it is `SCHED_FIFO`).

Answer (score 1):

The default policy of the thread will applicable in that case.

Check this.
[POSIX thread scheduling policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325078/posix-thread-scheduling-policies)

For more details information of kernel level you can check following link

http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html

Comment: Thanks Pradipta, the point that I'm looking for is not the default value that will be set. I'm trying to understand if there is a specific need of the system for any application to set the scheduler policy to some value, and what if I set it wrongly?

Comment: I suggest you just read the purpose of each type of scheduling policies then you will get what they mean and how they work .you will definitely get all your answers.

Comment: I know the purpose of each policy, but my question is how to find out from system point of view which one to be used

Comment: Its simple.System is very clever it will assign a default policy when ever it not finding what to do with the thread if no threading policy is defined.

Comment: One suggestion I can give.check the source code of POSIX library and check what it set when we are not giving any policy during thread creation.

Comment: I have given one link on scheduling in answer you can check.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.agr.unideb.hu/~agocs/informatics/11_e_unix/unixhelp/unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgib932.html?pthread_attr_setschedpolicy%203) the default schedpolicy is SCHED_OTHER.